# can I roast the nuts before I make a maple candied walnuts

Tags: dessert

Can I roast nuts for flavor before I make my maple candied walnuts? The recipe says raw nuts. I want to roast the nuts before I put in the maple candied walnuts recipe. Will that make the nuts overcooked

Comment: We can be more helpful if you provide the specific recipe that you're using. The answer might depend on what other steps are included.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend sticking to raw walnuts.  I recently prepared a batch of candied pecans and used raw pecans.  They turned out amazing and had sufficiently rich, roasted flavor.  Nuts can get bitter if they're roasted for too long. Roasting the nuts prior to putting them in the maple candied walnuts recipe might lead to over-roasting.

My recipe called for tossing the pecans in a one egg white (to develop a super thin, sticky coating) and then sprinkling them with cinnamon sugar before roasting.  They turned out amazing.  I've been snacking on them non-stop! Good luck!